# How to remove grainy detail from an line drawing (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter

Hi Im making a drawing app that can draw lines only with stylus device, I manifested the highlight pen method amd pictures are below link

https://velog.io/@kkorbilionaire/Removing-the-grainy-detail-from-line

I want to make a smooth line like second picture

this is my Painter class code

> CustomPainter Code

```
/// Highlighter Mode Painter Class
class HighlighterDrawingPainter extends CustomPainter {
  HighlighterDrawingPainter(this.lines);

  final List<List<DotInfo>> lines;
  double opacity = 0.3;
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (var oneLine in lines) {
      Color? color;
      double? size;
      var path = Path();
      var l = <Offset>[];
      for (var oneDot in oneLine) {
        color ??= oneDot.color;
        size ??= oneDot.size;
        l.add(oneDot.offset);
      }
      path.addPolygon(l, false);

      canvas.drawPath(
          path,
          Paint()
            ..color = color!.withOpacity(opacity)
            ..strokeWidth = size!
            ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.square
            ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
            ..isAntiAlias = true);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

what property should I use to remove the grainy details??

Answer (score 0):

I solved this Problem by adding

```
canvas.drawPath(path,
         Paint()
            ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
            ..isAntiAlias = true
```

these properties removed the grainy parts but still pressure sensitivity is too high so im looking how to reduce the pressure sensitivity